# Jqgrid change nav properties on callback function

Tags: dynamic, properties, jqgrid, navbar

i try to change the navbar properties on a jqgrid in a callback function without succes.

The grid is display afeter user is chosing a period. Depend on either the period is open or close user can or cannot edit, add, delete rows. So the navbar need to change properties dynamically.

My code look like that:

```
 $('#mygrid').jqGrid({

// some properties of my grid that works fine
pager : '#gridpager'

});

$("#mygrid").bind("jqGridLoadComplete",function(){
   $.ajax({
       url: 'checkifperiodopen.php',
       data: {
          $("#period").val()
       },
       success: function(data){
          if(period==='open'){
             jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{add:false,edit:false,del:true,search:true,refresh:true});
          }
         if(period==='close'){ 
            jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{add:true,edit:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true});
         }
       }
 });
});
 $('#validChossenPeriod').click(function () {
   ajax call to get data on choosen period
     success:function(data){
                    $("#mygrid").jqGrid('clearGridData');
                    $("#mygrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'local'});
                   $("#mygrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: data});
                   $("#mygrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
       }
  });
```

Comment: Do you want every time to change the navigator option when you do a sorting, paging searching? or you want to set these only once when the page load?. In your case this ajax call is executed every time you do something with the grid data.

Comment: Hello Tony, you're right, i just check and the ajax is trigger when i sort the table. it's not what i had in mind. i will modify my code to do this procedure only on 'validchosenperiod'.click (it's a submit button).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer by show or hide the div that include the navgrid button:

```
            grid = $("#mygrid");
            gid = $.jgrid.jqID(grid[0].id);
            var $tdadd = $('#add_' + gid);
            var $tdedit = $('#edit_' + gid);
            var $tddel = $('#del_' + gid);

          $("#mygrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{add:true,edit:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true});

           condition if false = 
                     $tdadd.hide();
                     $tdedit.hide();
                     $tddel.hide();
            if true =
                   $tdadd.show();
                   $tdedit.show();
                   $tddel.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so complex? There is a other clear way to do this

```
var view_buttons = true;
if(condition_to_hide) {
    view_buttons = false; 
}
$("#mygrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager', { add:view_buttons, edit:view_buttons, del:view_buttons, search:true, refresh:true});
```